# UINavigationItem titleView positioning issue

Tags: ios, uinavigationitem

I have an iPad application, and on one of the screens I have a `UIToolbar` set as the `titleView` of the `viewController`'s `navigationItem`. I also have a `left-` and a `rightBarButtonItem`.

When I enter the screen in landscape and rotate the device, the `titleView` remains centered. However if I do the opposite (enter in portrait and the rotate the device), the `titleView` is shifted to the right. Is there any way to fix this? Here is my code:

```
UIView *titleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 350, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height)];
UIToolbar *titleToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 350, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height)];
titleToolbar.items = @[commentButton, spacer2, downloadButton, spacer3, homeButton, spacer4, pageDisplayButton, spacer5, searchButton];
titleToolbar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
[titleView addSubview:titleToolbar];
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView;
```

**Edit:**

The `self.navigationItem.titleView.frame.size` is the same in both scenarios, the thing that changes is the `origin.x`

Comment: Try to use `sizeToFit`.

Comment: change position of your you NavigationController at the time you roted your deavice :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using toolbar , don't add titleView as subView. Instead add in items array.

```
UIToolbar *titleToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 350, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height)];

UIView *titleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 350, titleToolbar.frame.size.height)];
```

Add bar button item as titleViewBtn and make border plain.

```
titleToolbar.items = @[commentButton, spacer2, downloadButton, spacer3, homeButton, spacer4, **titleViewBtn** , pageDisplayButton, spacer5, searchButton];
titleToolbar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
```